# Regex to match golang sql dsn

Tags: php, regex, go, dsn

I'm having troubles matching the DSN used by golang. So I have two applications (golang and php) using the same config file, and that config file states DSN using golang dsn format, my idea is parse that dsn and use it into PHP's code. Any help on the right regexp?
Thanks!

Comment: Any attempts on said regex, or an example that explains your woes? Why not `parse_url` with a faux proto prefix?

Comment: DSN are not urls, a dsn follow this: `[username[:password]@][protocol[(address)]]/dbname[?param1=value1&...&paramN=valueN]`

Comment: Again, what are your problems with writing a regex for it? (And, btw, parse_url works quite well.)

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/kX8hK8/3

Comment: I've ended using http://regex101.com/r/hR5vZ0/1
Thanks!

Comment: @gchain you should post the regex as an answer and explain how you used it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For reference the go-sql-driver project uses this to parse the dsn. They moved away from using a regex

https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/blob/master/utils.go#L74

Here is the regex they used to use

https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/blob/f4bf8e8e0aa93d4ead0c6473503ca2f5d5eb65a8/utils.go#L34

If you look at the commit for the new parser it has much better performance (benchmarked for go 1.2 and 1.1)

https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/commit/dc029498cb5a3efbe44e54dcb5cf080d451450fa

Comment: awesome, that regexp was what I was looking for, thanks!